# How to set required validation in angular time picker?

Tags: angular, angular10

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Start Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                          <div class="cal-icon">
                            <input class="form-control datetimepicker" type="text" bsDatepicker
                                [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',  returnFocusToInput: true }"
                                [class.invalid]="addTaskForm.get('StartDate').invalid && addTaskForm.get('StartDate').touched"
                                formControlName="StartDate">
                          </div>

                          <div
                            *ngIf="addTaskForm.get('StartDate').invalid && addTaskForm.get('StartDate').touched">
                            <small
                                *ngIf="addTaskForm.get('StartDate').invalid && addTaskForm.get('StartDate').touched"
                                class="text-danger"> *Start Date is required</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <timepicker formControlName="taskStartTime"></timepicker>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It was given in the same way as in the other field but it did not work. After touching the time picker, show error message, how to do this ? I'm using angular 10

this is my ts

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

constructor()
{private formBuilder: FormBuilder}

export class TaskBoardComponent implements OnInit {
public addTaskForm: FormGroup;
}

ngOnInit() {

    this.addTaskForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          StartDate: ["", [Validators.required]],
          taskStartTime: ["", [Validators.required]],
          taskEndTime: ["", [Validators.required]],
        });
}
```

Comment: please post the code that you tried and for better understanding add any info about docs that you followed while implementing this..

Comment: seems like you added some class based input invalid case, also try to add those for timepicker as well